# In Angular4 with <routeroutlet> - On scroll of main/detail container, How to control navigation/scroll of side bar or left div

Tags: css, angular

On scrolling of main/detail container(div), How to control navigation/scroll of side bar or left div. Though I don't have any scroll separately on Div. I want to control this behavior on main window scrolling not on div since I don't want to apply any scroll to div. Find detail below-

1. I tried with Bootstrap "container-Fluid" But unable to get any expected outcome.
2. Than I moved with smth scrolling that using Angular directive. However I am not able to see the scroll event when I scroll window, however scroll event fired when I scroll right side div, which certainly I don't want to use since I don't want to use div with scroll explicitly instead I want to use main router-outlet scroll.

Now the problem is how to set the offset and decide that I am now on which section and correspondingly move the pointer or scroll of left div. (Note in my question I have used fixed size of div's, but in original code the size is not fixed. And only identifier is ID of section starts which matches with left side category sections). Now how to use DOCUMENT component on directive and highlight the respective element of Left side category menus.

Angular Directive ->

```js
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector:'[scroller]'
})

export class ScrollingDirective{
    public navIsFixed: boolean = false;
    constructor( @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }
    @HostListener('scroll') scrolling() {
        console.log('Scrolled1...');
      
    }

    @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
    onWindowScroll() {
        console.log('Scrolled2...');
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y62nQ.png)HTML Page ->

```css
<style>
    .full-width{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}

    .double-width{
    width:100%;
    height: 50%;
}   
    #section1 {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #1E88E5;
    }

    #section2 {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #673ab7;
    }

    #section3 {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #ff9800;
    }

    #section41 {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #00bcd4;
    }

    #section42 {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #009688;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 810px) {
        #section1, #section2, #section3, #section41, #section42 {
            margin-left: 150px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="full-width" scroller>
    <div class="double-width">
    <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20" scroller>
    <div class="container" scroller>
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="col-sm-3" id="myScrollspy">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" scroller>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div id="section1">
                    <h1>Section 1</h1>
                    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
                <div id="section2">
                    <h1>Section 2</h1>
                    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
                <div id="section3">
                    <h1>Section 3</h1>
                    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
                <div id="section41">
                    <h1>Section 4-1</h1>
                    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
                <div id="section42">
                    <h1>Section 4-2</h1>
                    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation   
                             list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error with approach I decided, I reached to solution and its working very nicely on all browser. Chrome and Edge has different sort of implementation for "JavaScript ***For*** loop". But its great to identify the behavior and fixing that as well....Please find the steps below to implement customized scrolling in Angular "".
1. Apply the directive selector(i.e. scroller) at your parent div on child screen, which has to use this scrolling.
2. Apply the class "scrlSpy" to all elements of Side navigation bar links or items and provide the id "sidenav" to the sidenav container.
3. Similarly apply "contentSpy" class to every section of main container of right side. and apply id's to container i.e. "contentCol".
4. And that's it at html pages.
5. Now just copy the below directive code and start using it by referring to your component or shared component.
Note :- make sure you have marked your first element as active by decoration with "active" class. otherwise twist your code if class name is different.

```js
import {Directive, HostListener, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Directive({
    selector: '[scroller]'
})

export class ScrollingDirective {
    allEle: any;
    allContent: any;
    i: number;
    activeEle: number;
    constructor( @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {

    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.allEle = this.document.getElementsByClassName('scrlSpy');
        this.allContent = this.document.getElementsByClassName('contentSpy');
        this.i = 0;
    }

    @HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event'])
    onWindowScroll(event) {
        let sideNav = this.document.getElementById('sidenav');
        let contentCol = this.document.getElementById('contentCol');
        let scrollOffset = this.document.body.scrollTop;
        let j: number = 0;
        let contentCollection: any[];
        this.activeEle = 0;
        if (scrollOffset > 100) {
            sideNav.classList.add("sideNaveMargintop");
            contentCol.classList.add("fltRight");
        }
        else {
            contentCol.classList.remove("fltRight");
            sideNav.classList.remove("sideNaveMargintop");
        }
        for (let ele in this.allEle) {
            if (ele != null && j < this.allEle.length) {
                var element = this.document.getElementById(this.allEle[ele].id).classList.contains("active");
                if (element === true) {
                    break;
                }
                this.activeEle++;
            }
        }
        for (let cont in this.allContent) {
            if (cont != null && this.i < this.allContent.length && this.i > 0 && 
                this.activeEle < this.allContent.length - 1) {
                let contentEle = this.document.getElementById(this.allContent[cont].id);                
                if (contentEle != null) {
                    if (scrollOffset >= this.allContent[this.activeEle + 1].offsetTop) {
                        this.document.getElementById(this.allEle[this.activeEle].id).classList.remove("active");
                        this.document.getElementById(this.allEle[this.activeEle + 1].id).classList.add("active");
                    }
                    else if (scrollOffset <= this.allContent[this.activeEle].offsetTop && this.activeEle - 1 >= 0) {
                        this.document.getElementById(this.allEle[this.activeEle].id).classList.remove("active");
                        this.document.getElementById(this.allEle[this.activeEle - 1].id).classList.add("active");
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (this.allContent.length - 1 == this.activeEle && scrollOffset <= this.allContent[this.activeEle].offsetTop) {
                this.document.getElementById(this.allEle[this.activeEle].id).classList.remove("active");
                this.document.getElementById(this.allEle[this.activeEle - 1].id).classList.add("active");
            }
            this.i++;
        }

        this.i = 0;
        j = 0;
    }
}
```